# replace the text with pre and post string

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I have file in which there are certian lines which have common string:

```
_report_file <<
```

SO the text around this above can be any thingbut it ends with semiclon(;)
for eg see the line below:

```
CACUP_updater::_report_file << "The job has terminated." << endl;
```

another example of the line can be:

```
_report_file << "The job is reading." << endl;
```

i need to append `abc;` as pre string and `xyz;` as post string to that line so that the line looks like

```
abc;CACUP_updater::_report_file << "The job has terminated." << endl;xyz;
```

basically i want to search for `"_report_file <<"`,select the complete line and pre and post append some text.
how can i do this in sed or perl or awk.

Comment: I've updated my answer to match the updated question. I interpreted the question a little bit more systematically than you posed it, I expect it suits your case.

Answer (score 1):

A perl way:

```
perl -anE 'chomp;s/^(.*?::_report_file <<.*;)$/abc;$1xyz;/;say;' foo.txt > foo2.txt
```

or

```
perl -ane 'chomp;s/^(.*?::_report_file <<.*;)$/abc;${1}xyz;/;print "$_\n";' foo.txt > foo2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** in response to your updated question. I think you're doing it wrong :)

I suggest you do it this way instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>)
{
    s/([\w]+::)?_report_file\s*<<\s*(.*);/CACUP_REPORT($2);/go;
    print
}
```

That way, you can, in C++, define a macro like

```
#define CACUP_REPORT(message) do { \
    /* abc; */ \
    ::CACUP_updater::_report_file << message; \
    /* xyz; */ } while (false)
```

#### But Why?

- You can read all about *safe* macros elsewhere **<sup>1</sup>**.
- You get way more flexibility. You can later change all instances at one point.
- You can delegate to a a function
- You could declare a temporary `stringstream` and write the resulting text to a whole other medium (network? fwrite? memory buffer? two streams?).
- You could make the logging conditional depending on a global falg without having to duplicate the check for it throughour your code.

Well you get it: it pretty much the **[DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) [principle](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html)**.

### Sample input:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace CACUP_updater
{
    std::ostream& _report_file = std::cout;

    void start_reading()
    {
        _report_file << "The job is reading." << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CACUP_updater::_report_file << "The job is starting." << endl;
    CACUP_updater::start_reading();
    CACUP_updater::_report_file << "The job has terminated." << endl;
}
```

### Sample output:

The result of, e.g. `perl -i.bck test.cpp` is **<sup>2</sup>**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace CACUP_updater
{
    std::ostream& _report_file = std::cout;

    void start_reading()
    {
        CACUP_REPORT("The job is reading." << endl);
    }
}

int main()
{
    CACUP_REPORT("The job is starting." << endl);
    CACUP_updater::start_reading();
    CACUP_REPORT("The job has terminated." << endl);
}
```

#### Some ideas for implementations of the macro:

This shows how you can

- use a temporary stream to stringify
- print to more than one output stream, conditionally
- handle exceptions properly inline
- add a datetime stamp (only for writing to the log file, not stderr)
- of course, there is more than enough room to accomodate any `abc;` or `xyz;` you had in mind :)

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

static bool _verbose = false;

#define CACUP_REPORT(message) do { \
    std::stringstream ss; \
    ss << message; \
    ::CACUP_updater::log_helper(ss.str()); \
    } while (false)

namespace CACUP_updater
{
    std::string getdatetime() { return "YYYY/MM/DD - HH:MM:SS.mmm"; } // demo only
    void log_helper(const std::string& msg)
    {
        try
        {
            std::ofstream ofs("/tmp/myprogram.log", std::ios_base::app);

            ofs << getdatetime() << "\t" << msg;
            ofs.flush();
            ofs.close();

            // log errors always to stderr, 
            // and all other messages if verbose is set
            if (_verbose || std::string::npos != msg.find("ERROR"))
                std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
        } catch(std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Unhandled error writing to log: '" << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void start_reading()
    {
        CACUP_REPORT("The job is reading." << endl);
    }
}

int main()
{
    CACUP_REPORT("The job is starting." << endl);
    CACUP_updater::start_reading();
    CACUP_REPORT("The job has terminated." << endl);
}
```

The output to the file is:

```
YYYY/MM/DD - HH:MM:SS.mmm   The job is starting.
YYYY/MM/DD - HH:MM:SS.mmm   The job is reading.
YYYY/MM/DD - HH:MM:SS.mmm   The job has terminated.
```

The output to the stderr depends on the `verbose` flag

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> just imagine what would happen if `if (b) _report_file << "ok!" << std::endl;` ?</sub>

<sup>2</sup> note that a backup file is created: `test.cpp.bck`

Comment: @RahulDravid: I address your edit in a comprehensive way (I also added inspiration for implementing your own logger macro with all bells and whistles). Hope you like it

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `CACUP_REPORT("The job has terminated." << endl);` - this doesn't look like C++ anymore with the `<<` inside the parenthesis.  Sure, with sufficient operator overloading, that can be valid standalone code, but I suggest its too obtuse.

Comment: @Tanktalus: I didn't design the problem, just for your information. It is the best solution to the conundrum the OP is in.

Comment: I didn't say you designed the problem. You appeared to take the question as an XY problem (which it probably is), and proposed a solution somewhat orthogonal to the question.  My issue wasn't that you did this (it's how I answer questions very often), merely that your orthogonal solution introduces a whole different readability issue.  If your macro allowed the `<<` to remain on the outside of the parens, e.g., `CACUP_REPORT("message") << endl;`, that'd be fine by me (a "function" returning ostream& is reasonable), but wouldn't quite match the OP, either.

Comment: @Tanktalus: be-that-as-it-may there is no other general solution that doesn't require extensive assumptions about how his code uses the `_report_file`, and I don't wish to send the OP to a host of new problems. Moreover, this solution is orders of magnitude better than the strategy he was following in the OP. Lastly, if readability issues are a factor at all, I will gladly let the OP decide. (IOW: I agree; just +1  me for the effort and I'll try to forget I wrote a CPP macro today... <smile/>)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -i.bak -n -e 'print "abc;${_}xyz;"' your_file_here
```

That'll give you a backup copy of the file too.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/_report_file <</{$0="abc;" $0 "xyz;"}{print}'
```

Comment: i suppose this will print only the lines which has the string not the remaining lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's{.*_report_file <<.*}{abc;$&xyz;}' file_name_here
```